# Как правильно написать Prometheus Exporter?

Tags: golang, prometheus

Есть следующий код, на основе которого мне нужно создать метрики.
У меня есть слайс, содержащий структуры, описывающие кластера.
Вот эта структура:

```
type Cluster struct {
    Clustername string
    Vdcname     string
    IsPause     string
}
```

Я получаю данные из моей системы по каждому из кластеров и засовываю в слайс Clusters эти структуры:

```
var Clusters []*entities.Cluster
```

Есть вывести его, то у меня там вот такое:

```
&{sks-cluster-1 dc-something-1 false}
&{sks-cluster-2 dc-something-2 true}
&{sks-cluster-3 dc-something-3 false}
&{sks-cluster-4 dc-something-4 true}
&{sks-cluster-5 dc-something-5 false}
&{sks-cluster-6 dc-something-6 false}
```

И теперь для каждой этой записи мне нужно создать метрики вида:

```
foo_metric{cluster_name="sks-cluster-1", vdcname="dc-something-1", value="false"} 0
foo_metric{cluster_name="sks-cluster-2", vdcname="dc-something-2", value="true"} 1
```

Подскажите как это правильно сделать на основе примера, который я приложил ниже:

```
package exporter

import (
    "math/rand"
    "time"

    "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus"
    "github.com/vsfomin/prometheus_exporter/internal/entities"
)

// Define a struct for you collector that contains pointers
// to prometheus descriptors for each metric you wish to expose.
// Note you can also include fields of other types if they provide utility
// but we just won't be exposing them as metrics.
type fooCollector struct {
    fooMetric      *prometheus.Desc
    barMetric      *prometheus.Desc
    kuberConnector KuberConnIntf
}

type KuberConnIntf interface {
    GetClusters() ([]*entities.Cluster, error)
}

// You must create a constructor for you collector that
// initializes every descriptor and returns a pointer to the collector
func NewFooCollector(kuberConn KuberConnIntf) *fooCollector {
    labels := map[string]string{"test": "suka", "some": "other"}

    return &fooCollector{

        fooMetric: prometheus.NewDesc("foo_metric",
            "Shows whether a foo has occurred in our cluster",
            nil, labels,
        ),
        barMetric: prometheus.NewDesc("bar_metric",
            "Shows whether a bar has occurred in our cluster",
            nil, labels,
        ),
        kuberConnector: kuberConn,
    }
}

// Each and every collector must implement the Describe function.
// It essentially writes all descriptors to the prometheus desc channel.
func (collector *fooCollector) Describe(ch chan<- *prometheus.Desc) {

    //Update this section with the each metric you create for a given collector
    ch <- collector.fooMetric
    ch <- collector.barMetric
}

// Collect implements required collect function for all promehteus collectors
func (collector *fooCollector) Collect(ch chan<- prometheus.Metric) {

    //Implement logic here to determine proper metric value to return to prometheus
    //for each descriptor or call other functions that do so.
    var metricValue float64
    if 1 == 1 {
        metricValue += rand.Float64()
    }

    //Write latest value for each metric in the prometheus metric channel.
    //Note that you can pass CounterValue, GaugeValue, or UntypedValue types here.
    m1 := prometheus.MustNewConstMetric(collector.fooMetric, prometheus.GaugeValue, metricValue)
    m2 := prometheus.MustNewConstMetric(collector.barMetric, prometheus.GaugeValue, metricValue)
    m1 = prometheus.NewMetricWithTimestamp(time.Now().Add(-time.Hour), m1)
    m2 = prometheus.NewMetricWithTimestamp(time.Now(), m2)
    ch <- m1
    ch <- m2
}

func (collector *fooCollector) Test() {
    collector.kuberConnector.GetClusters()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

для этих целей вам нужен `GaugeVec`

```
import (
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "net/http"
    "time"

    "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus"
    "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus/promhttp"
)

// Define a struct for you collector that contains pointers
// to prometheus descriptors for each metric you wish to expose.
// Note you can also include fields of other types if they provide utility
// but we just won't be exposing them as metrics.
type fooCollector struct {
    fooMetric      *prometheus.Desc
    barMetric      *prometheus.Desc
    gmetric        *prometheus.GaugeVec
    kuberConnector KuberConnIntf
}

type Cluster struct {
    Clustername string
    Vdcname     string
    IsPause     string
}

type KuberConnIntf interface {
    GetClusters() ([]*Cluster, error)
}

// You must create a constructor for you collector that
// initializes every descriptor and returns a pointer to the collector
func NewFooCollector(kuberConn KuberConnIntf, reg *prometheus.Registry) *fooCollector {
    labels := map[string]string{"test": "sam takoy", "some": "other"}

    f := &fooCollector{

        gmetric: prometheus.NewGaugeVec(prometheus.GaugeOpts{
            Name: "my_custom_metric",
            Help: "Custom description",
        }, []string{"cluster_name", "vdcname", "value"}),
        fooMetric: prometheus.NewDesc("foo_metric",
            "Shows whether a foo has occurred in our cluster",
            nil, labels,
        ),
        barMetric: prometheus.NewDesc("bar_metric",
            "Shows whether a bar has occurred in our cluster",
            nil, labels,
        ),
        kuberConnector: kuberConn,
    }

    reg.MustRegister(f.gmetric)
    return f
}

// Each and every collector must implement the Describe function.
// It essentially writes all descriptors to the prometheus desc channel.
func (collector *fooCollector) Describe(ch chan<- *prometheus.Desc) {

    // Update this section with the each metric you create for a given collector
    ch <- collector.fooMetric
    ch <- collector.barMetric
}

// Collect implements required collect function for all promehteus collectors
func (collector *fooCollector) Collect(ch chan<- prometheus.Metric) {

    // Implement logic here to determine proper metric value to return to prometheus
    // for each descriptor or call other functions that do so.
    var metricValue float64
    if 1 == 1 {
        metricValue += rand.Float64()
    }

    clusters, _ := collector.kuberConnector.GetClusters()
    for _, cluster := range clusters {
        labels := map[string]string{"cluster_name": cluster.Clustername, "vdcname": cluster.Vdcname, "value": cluster.IsPause}
        collector.gmetric.With(labels).Set(metricValue)
    }

    // Write latest value for each metric in the prometheus metric channel.
    // Note that you can pass CounterValue, GaugeValue, or UntypedValue types here.
    m1 := prometheus.MustNewConstMetric(collector.fooMetric, prometheus.GaugeValue, metricValue)
    m2 := prometheus.MustNewConstMetric(collector.barMetric, prometheus.GaugeValue, metricValue)
    m1 = prometheus.NewMetricWithTimestamp(time.Now().Add(-time.Hour), m1)
    m2 = prometheus.NewMetricWithTimestamp(time.Now(), m2)
    ch <- m1
    ch <- m2

}

func main() {

    // Since we are dealing with custom Collector implementations, it might
    // be a good idea to try it out with a pedantic registry.
    reg := prometheus.NewPedanticRegistry()

    // Add the standard process and Go metrics to the custom registry.
    reg.MustRegister(
        prometheus.NewProcessCollector(prometheus.ProcessCollectorOpts{}),
        prometheus.NewGoCollector(),
    )

    foo := NewFooCollector(&data{}, reg)
    err := reg.Register(foo)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    http.Handle("/metrics", promhttp.HandlerFor(reg, promhttp.HandlerOpts{}))
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))

}

type data struct {
}

func (d *data) GetClusters() ([]*Cluster, error) {
    return []*Cluster{
        {
            Clustername: "cluster1",
            Vdcname:     "vdc1",
            IsPause:     "true",
        },
        {
            Clustername: "cluster2",
            Vdcname:     "vdc2",
            IsPause:     "false",
        },
    }, nil
}
```

откройте http://localhost:8080/metrics

```
# HELP my_custom_metric Time when the last request was processed
# TYPE my_custom_metric gauge
my_custom_metric{cluster_name="cluster1",value="true",vdcname="vdc1"} 0.4246374970712657
my_custom_metric{cluster_name="cluster2",value="false",vdcname="vdc2"} 0.4246374970712657
```